# Karate framework - mock server define thread pool

Tags: java, karate, mockserver

I'm using karate framework for load testing and ruining mock server using following command with -T option to achive higher tps and it seems it is not effected and its always run 8 threads which is number of cores in the server.

```
  java -jar karate-0.9.5.RC5.jar -T 100 -m featurefilename.feature -p 8080
```

Kindly help to define thread pool count for the karate mock server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently supported. I can also confirm that this is not a priority for the project. You are welcome to contribute code, the relevant part is here: [`FeatureServer.java`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/netty/FeatureServer.java).

Comment: Thank you I was trying to modify source code. I got source from github and it seems KarateParserBaseListener is missing on  that package com.intuit.karate.core and unable to build it

Comment: @someone please refer this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide

Comment: I increased size of worker group and it resolved. Thank you